# Get all the Parent documents base on child reference Id Mongo and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reference, one-to-many

Thank you for your help.

I am scratching my head all day, I don't know I am in the right direction or not.

Problem :

I have a document [Doctor] which contains the reference [doctorSpecialities].

**I have to GET ALL DOCTORS who have this id in there doctorSpecialities reference Array**

```js
Id : 5ef58dd048cdd203a0c07ba8
```

JSON Structure

```
{
 "doctorSpecialities": [
    "5f00cebc8bcdcd0660c12ce2",
    "5ef58dd048cdd203a0c07ba8"
 ]
"_id": "5ef31ae80399ac05eb23e555",
"email": "signup@gmail.com",
"username": "signup@gmail.com",
"DOB": null,
"zip": null,
"phone": "12657334566",
"PMDC": "7658493",
"isVerified": false,
"aboutMe": "About Me",
"achievements": "Achievements",
"address": "padasdad",
"city": "Lahore",
"gender": "Male",
"managePractice": "Manage Practice",
"practiceGrowth": "Practice Growth",
"qualiflication": "Qualifcation",
"state": "eeeeeeee",
"workExperince": "Work Experince",
"doctorAvailability": [],
"doctorReviews": [],
"degreeCompletionYear": "2019-10-10",
"institute": "institute",
"practiceDate": "2020-10-10",
"services": "Dental"
},
```

**Query tried**

```
 await Doctor.find({ doctorSpecialities : req.params.id})

 await Doctor.find({ doctorSpecialities :{$in [ req.params.id}})
```

**Specialty Collection**

```js
  doctorCollection = Doctor.find();
  doctorCollection.find({"doctorSpecialities": specialty.id})
```

This is how I did is it wrong?

I tried to user $Lookup but I don't know how to use it in this requirement

Please let me know if you need more information.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have another collection where this id is used? I mean ids in the specialities array

Comment: Yes, I don't know why you asked it but if you are saying that I should go for embedded . These specialities are used for other purposes as well

Comment: No. Do you have speciality collection? This collection looks liks doctors details. How did you try lookup? We need details to help you.

Comment: Yes, I have the Speciality collection. I have added the collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to get `doctors` details then you can use

```
db.collection.find({"doctorSpecialities":"5ef58dd048cdd203a0c07ba8"})
```

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8XNkHAc1ogB)

It returns all documents where `doctorSpecialities` field contains `5ef58dd048cdd203a0c07ba8`

Comment: but this would give me all doctors at first then I have to query on it. can't we do it in one query?

Comment: Are you looking for speciality details?

Comment: No all the doctors having this specialty

Comment: ok, Is your first document for doctors? Second for specialities? And you need to get where specialities array field in doctor collection matches a given id? Is it correct? Then above query does it. If not, could you add expected output also as how you added two documents?

Comment: I have added the code is that fine don't know I am adding correctly or not

Comment: What do you mean by one query? It is single find query. Could you explain

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219080/discussion-between-malik-and-gibbs).